# laravel send json object by ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

```js
$.ajax({ 
    url: '{{ route('add.orders') }}',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
     myArr : myArr
      }),
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       success: function(data) {
       alert(data);
    }
    })
```

my controller:

```js
public function addOrders(Request $request) {
        return $request->myArr;
    }
```

I'm getting this one:

[image: this]

this is myArr:

[image]

How can i reach the object? Why it seems [object Object]
Can i reach myArr[0].id
İf you help me i will be glad, thank you.

Comment: show your input field myArr .

Comment: I added now, thanks for your answer

Comment: Use console.log instead of alert function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like below

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

    console.log(data[i].id);

    console.log(data[i].food_title);

}
```

Comment: Yes it's working, but i must use it in my controller, how can i reach it in my controller. If you help me i will be glad. Ex:  $request->myArr[0]->id    is not working

Comment: `dd($request->all())` first and share your result

Comment: if I use dd() function i can not see any message on the console. so i have to use return $request->all() , i edit and added to my first message

Comment: Yes. You can't get any data in console log. Because it exit before return

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: "{{ route('add.orders') }}",
   headers: {
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
   },
   data:{ myData: JSON.stringify(myArr),_token:"{{ csrf_token() }}" },
   cache: false,
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
   }
});


#At Controller

public function addOrders(Request $request) {
    dd($request->all());
}
```